Handling Server-Side Image Rendering with Sanity Client in Next.js App Router: Overcoming Client-Side Mapping Challenges
I am converting a Next/Sanity project to the app router.
The image component needs to be rendered on the server side because it makes use of the sanity client and the boilerplate includes the import 'server-only' directive.
I have hit the following blocker in a couple of places where a client component requires me to render images as children of a map (or in this case a value changes depending on which mapped item is clicked) and pass resultant image data to the SanityImage component.
I know that I can keep the SanityImage component on the server side by passing it to the client component as either children or a prop. But how can I have the map in the client-side when the server-side SanityImage component needs to receive props from the client component? Image data for instance.
Currently (as you will see below) I have the server component passing the SanityImage component down to the client component via props and the client component passing the image data to it, as comes naturally to me. However, I am aware that lack of serialisation makes this impossible to do across the client-server boundary.
Another rookie error I tried: Setting up a context/provider to wrap the SanityImage component and pass down props via context.
The only solutions I have seen are to add a search query value to the URL, which triggers regeneration. But not ideal in all cases from a UX perspective.
Is there a path to resolving this? All thoughts and suggestions much appreciated.
'client' used in server component SanityImage.tsx
const sanityImageProps: UseNextSanityImageProps = useNextSanityImage(
    client,
    image?.asset
  );

sanity.client.ts
import 'server-only';

import {createClient} from 'next-sanity';

import {apiVersion, dataset, projectId} from '../lib/sanity.api';

export const client = createClient({
  projectId,
  dataset,
  apiVersion, // https://www.sanity.io/docs/api-versioning
  useCdn: true, // Set to false if statically generating pages, using ISR or tag-based revalidation
  stega: {
    enabled: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV === 'preview',
    studioUrl: '/studio',
  },
});

ServerSideParent.tsx (does not work)
const ServerSideParent = ({items, heading, imageLeft = false}: Props) => {
  const sanityImageDesktop = (imageProp: Image, titleProp: string) => (
    <SanityImage
      key={titleProp}
      image={imageProp}
    />
  );

  return (
    <ClientSideChild
      items={items}
      heading={heading}
      imageLeft={imageLeft}
      sanityImageDesktop={sanityImageDesktop}
    />
  );
};

export default ServerSideParent;

ClientSideChild.tsx (does not work)
'use client';

const ClientSideChild = ({ items, sanityImageDesktop}: Props) => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  const {image, title} = useMemo(() => {
    const data = items.filter((item) => item.disable !== true);
    return data[activeIndex];
  }, [activeIndex, items]);

  const filteredItems = useMemo(() => {
    return items.filter((item) => item.disable !== true);
  }, [items]);

  return (
      <div>
          <nav>
              {filteredItems.map(({title}, i) => (
                <button onClick={() => setActiveIndex(i)} key={title}>
                  {title}
                </button>
              ))}
           </nav>
        <div>{sanityImageDesktop(image, title)}</div>
      </div>
  );
};

export default ClientSideChild;

